# Example of an open cover of $(0, 1)$ with no finite subcover

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

**Question:** Let $F$ be the interval $(0,1)$ and find an open cover $G$ such that no finite sub-collection of $G$ covers $F$.

I believe I have the answer I would appreciate some reassurance of my answer or if it is wrong a correction.

**Answer:** Let $F$ be the interval $(0,1)$ and let $G$ be the set $(0,1-\frac{1}{n})$ where $n=1,2,3,\dots$

It is obvious that $G$ covers $F$ but no finite sub-collection of $G$ could because the set $F$ is open.

Comment: What do you mean by "because the set $F$ is open"?

Comment: meaning that no matter how close I get to 1 i will never reach it, there is always a larger number past any number I pick close to 1.

Comment: Intuitively that's what's going on, but that is not a proof.

Comment: Yeah I guess it is more of a solution

Comment: But does the example I chose meet the requirements of the question?

Comment: Yes, that cover works.

Comment: Very close.  if you take a finite number of the intervals $U_n= (1 - 1/n)$ then of the finite collection there must be a maximum value of n, call it N.  Then no $x \in [1- 1/N, 1)$ is covered by the finite subcover.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G_n = (0, 1 - \frac{1}{n})$, then as I pointed out in the comments, $G := \{G_n \mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a cover for $(0, 1)$ which has no finite subcover (so $(0, 1)$ is not compact).

To see that it is a cover, let $x \in (0, 1)$, then $1 - x > 0$. By the Archimedean property of the real numbers, there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N} < 1 - x$, and hence $x < 1 - \frac{1}{N}$, so $x \in G_N$.

Now consider $\{G_{n_k} \mid k = 1, \dots, K\} \subset G$. Note that as $G_{n_1} \subset G_{n_2} \subset \dots \subset G_{n_K}$, $\bigcup_{k=1}^KG_{n_k} = G_{n_K} = (0, 1 - \frac{1}{n_K}) \subsetneqq (0, 1)$. Therefore $G$ does not have a finite subcover.